# Representing extension method using lambda expression

Tags: c#

I have a simple extension method which converts Timespan to String representation.

```
public static string getTime(this TimeSpan ts)
{
    return ts.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

I was thinking if there's a way to convert this method to a simple lambda expression. 
Something like the following:

```
public static Func<TimeSpan, string> time = (this ts) => "HH:mm:ss";
```

However adding `this` keyword with the method param results in error.

**Keyword this is not valid in a static property, static method or static field initializer.**

Comment: Your two code blocks are totally different from one another, one's a routine the other is a field. Also, why the extension method, there's nothing gained here, `TimeSpan` does have `ToString`. Also, why a lambda expression, there's not a case for one, also it can be done if you really want one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods have to be methods. A static Func field is not a method.

You can use expression syntax to reduce the length of your extension;

```cs
public static string getTime(this TimeSpan ts) => ts.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Since that doesn't change how the method is compiled.